# In Unity, how can I pre load a video attached to a plane object?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, vuforia

I working on an AR application using Unity and Vuforia. It works fine, I attached a video to a plane object, however, I would like to show a spinner (or something like that) as the video loads in memory.

I attached my video (mp4) to a **Plane** GameObject (inside the Image Target), as you can see in the image below.

This is my hierarchy:

[image]

This is my snippet:

```cs
protected virtual void Start()
    {
        plane = GameObject.Find("Plane");
        videoPlayer = plane.transform.GetChild(0).gameObject;
        Debug.Log("Plane:  " + videoPlayer.isPlaying);

        mObserverBehaviour = GetComponent<ObserverBehaviour>();

        if (mObserverBehaviour)
        {
            mObserverBehaviour.OnTargetStatusChanged += OnObserverStatusChanged;
            mObserverBehaviour.OnBehaviourDestroyed += OnObserverDestroyed;
            
            OnObserverStatusChanged(mObserverBehaviour, mObserverBehaviour.TargetStatus);
        }

    }
```

I don't know how to get the **VideoClip** from the plane object and use the `VideoClip.prepared` method to preload. Appreciate any help!

Comment: Please use the correct tags! Note that [`[unityscript]`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/unityscript/info) is or better **was** a custom JavaScript flavor-like language used in early Unity versions and is **long deprecated** by now. Your code is clearly in `c#` ..

Comment: By `VideoClip` I guess you mean `VideoPlayer` component. I would attach another gameobject next to the plane to display the loading indicator inactive by default. When you invoke the `VideoPlayer.Prepare()` method on your you can activate the indicator gameobject and then make it inactive on the `VideoPlayer.prepareCompleted` event. Also I would use serialized fields instead of seeking for specific gameobjects like you did in this particular case.